# mongodb replication + sharding consistency

Tags: mongodb

I have a doubt (well a couple). I think i grasp the answer, but im looking for a confirm

lets say i would implement a sharded cluster of mongodb, is that necessary to have a replica set lying beside shards?

I know that if i use only the replicaSet, and i decide to distribute the reading operation on the secondary nodes, it will cause the eventual-consistency, right? 
and in the other hand if i don't enable reads on secondary nodes, the "only" advantage i will get is to protect the database in case of a node will fall

but what about the consistency in a sharded-replicaset? it will still be eventual-consistent or it will be full consistent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is that necessary to have a replica set lying beside shards

You don't have to but if you care for availability you will.

> and i decide to distribute the reading operation on the secondary nodes, it will cause the eventual-consistency, right?

Yes and since secondaries gather as much OPs as primaries and most drivers will only read from one active secondary reading from secondary is quite useless.

> the "only" advantage i will get is to protect the database in case of a node will fall

The "only"? That is the whole point of replica sets, to produce automatic fail over. That is there fundamental reason for existing and it is a big one.

> it will still be eventual-consistent or it will be full consistent?

It depends on where you do your reads but if you read from secondaries in a sharded setup you not only get eventual consistency but due to chunk movement you might also get duplicate documents.

If you are reading from primaries then you will get strong consistency in a sharded replica set setup.

Comment: thank you for the answer! i putted "only" inside inverted commas exactly because i didn't wanted to debase the advantage it brings. Sorry i should have use an other word, its my english XD

Im trying to understand why in the last sentence you said: reading from primaries. i mean, why plural? there can be more than a primary in a sharded cluster?

Comment: @lese sure a sharded replica setup is where each shard is infact a primary

Comment: @lese sorry wrote that fast, each shard is a replica set with its own primary and secondaries

Comment: @ sammaye : great! that was exactly what i was missing understanding :)

also, trying to improve availability by enable readings on secondaries always involve a concistency problematics! damn eheh